# Media Query - Bootstrap site not working on IExplorer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, explorer

I'm new at this, I'm having this template which works great on Firefox and Chrome, but on IExplorer it looks like the mediaqueries are not working.

Is there any .js or plugin or something that would make this just work?

this is the template: 
http://ofimetsistemas.com.ar/test/

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about IE8, it doesn't understand media queries. Per the Bootstrap docs:

> In addition, Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to enable media query support.

Comment: In which version of IE? All of them?

Comment: In IE8, I downloaded the zip on GitHub, added the responsive.min.js but nothing, I have no clue!

Comment: @Agustín Bootstrap 3 doesn't have a responsive.min.js... that's Bootstrap 2. http://ofimetsistemas.com.ar/test/css/bootstrap.css shows you're using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: and is there any solution for IE8 and boostrap 3 that you know?

Comment: Yes. Don't mix Bootstrap 3 and 2. Use one or the other. If you're using Bootstrap 3, include Respond.js properly. Not responsive.min.css, Respond.js.